# nested_form and Single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I'm having trouble using it with STI and wondered if you can give me some pointers.
I want to add attachments to discussion as well.
I tried several attempts to make it work but always got exceptions.

do i need to add accepts_nested_attributes_for in discussion.rb ?
do i need to add a column in the attachments table ?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:url].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Discussion  < Post
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :post
end
```

Comment: if some attachments are linked to some posts, you'll need to add the post_id in your attachment table

Answer (score 0):

> do i need to add accepts_nested_attributes_for in discussion.rb ?

If there is now any differences with parent class - No

> do i need to add a column in the attachments table ?

Only `post_id` or any other key

Comment: Do i need to add accepts_nested_attributes_for in discussion.rb ? and has_many :attachments, :dependent => :destroy ?

Comment: No. It willbe enough to be placed in parent class